# When is it appropriate to use std::optional

Tags: c++, stl, return, unique-ptr, stdoptional

I was wondering if this would be considered a valid usage of std::optional. I have a function that returns a `process_id` (`std::uint32_t` value), would it be more efficient to have a standard "`std::uint32_t`" function that returns 0 if we fail to find the target processes ID or would returning a std::optional be more appropriate?

example:

```
std::optional<std::uint32_t> FindProcessID(std::string_view process)
{
    bool find = false;

    if (!find)
        // we fail to find the process_id and return nothing.
        return std::nullopt;
    else if (find)
        return 100; // return the id
}
```

I am also doing this when returning a unique_ptr as-well opposed to just returning a nullptr, but I am unsure if this would be considered "abuse" of said feature, and if it would be better just to return 0 and check for that value. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11):

> I was wondering if this would be considered a valid usage of `std::optional`

Yes, yes, yes - this is what `std::optional` is for!

> would it be more efficient to return 0 if we fail

Technically yes, `std::optional` is a wrapper, so it comes with a tiny overhead. The likelihood that this is a performance bottleneck in your code is, however, extremely low. If unsure, create a benchmark and compare the two versions of your function.

> I am currently doing this when returning a unique_ptr as-well, but I am unsure if this would be considered "abuse" of said feature

This is indeed not the intended, idiomatic use case for `std::unique_ptr`. Readers of your code would expect the `std::unique_ptr` to handle exclusive ownership of some (possibly polymorphic) object. Neither are there many valid scenarios to put a primitive integral type into a smart pointer, nor is it good practice to use `std::unique_ptr` for a use case that's perfect for `std::optional`.

Comment: Not to mention `unique_ptr` forces dynamic allocation when there's no good reason to do so for this use case.

Comment: Thank you for the information & help! The unique_ptr is being used to achieve RAII with WINAPI handles with a custom deleter. The function either opens the handle or returns std::nullopt via std::optional.

Comment: Ah, so the `std::unique_ptr` isn't meant to wrap around the `uint32_t`? Sorry, then I understood the last part of your question incorrectly. Using `std::unique_ptr` as a RAII wrapper with a custom deleter is absolutely fine!